# Tomcat springboot application LifecycleException

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have an SpringBoot aplication that works on my Spring Tool Suite, but when i try to deploy it on a tomcat(8) server on other machine i get this:

```
FAIL - Application at context path [/aplicacoes] could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception [org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/aplicacoes]]]
```

I found a lot of different explanations and none worked, yet.
Anyone have any idea what it can be?

EDIT: My POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>br.org.cepedi</groupId>
    <artifactId>aplicacoes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>aplicacoes</name>
    <description>Sistema que exibe as urls das aplicações desenvolvidas no CEPEDI</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: don't you have a stacktrace?

Comment: to generate the war, are you not including the tomcat embedded libraries right?

Comment: @GuyBouallet I don't know how to get the stacktrace on tomcat. And my logs/catalina.out don't return any error.

Comment: @cralfaro No, i'm generating the war by command line mvn clean verify package.

Comment: could you share your pom?

Comment: @cralfaro Edited

Comment: Check your Tomcat configs to find out where the logs are being written.  For a start, look for the logging.properties file.  Without a stacktrace, we are unlikely to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I re-downloaded the Tomcat and re-instaled the postgres and now just works.